# Vanilla Javascript: .forEach Loop Not Applying Event Listener

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, addeventlistener

Looking for some support on why this loop is not applying the `eventlisteners` to the 2 image elements.

HTML:

```html
<img src="video-embed.jpg" alt="text content">
<img src="video-embed-copy.jpg" alt="text content">
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
let videoThumbnails = document.querySelectorAll('img[src*="video-embed"]');
    
function toggleGalleryModal(modal) {
    console.log(clicked);
    document.getElementById(modal).classList.toggle("show-modal");
}
    
function buildGalleryModals() {
    
    videoThumbnails.forEach(function (thumbnail, index) {
        let modalID = 'vid-gallery-modal-' + index,
            altText = thumbnail.alt;
    
        thumbnail.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            console.log('thumbnail[i]: ' + index);
        });
    
        document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="' + modalID + '" class="vid-gallery-modal"><div class="modal-content"><span class="close-button">×</span>' + altText + '</div></div>';
    });
}
    
buildGalleryModals();
```

Comment: have you verified that `videoThumbnails` contains the two expected DOM elements?

Comment: Yes, the elements exist. The modals actually generate (both) at the end of the body, but they do not receive the click listeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that after you set up the click handlers, you overwrite the `document.body.innerHTML` with new HTML elements and wipe out the elements that you just set up.

Instead, inject that new HTML into a portion of the document, but not the `document.body`.

```js
let videoThumbnails = document.querySelectorAll('img[src*="video-embed"]');

function toggleGalleryModal(modal) {
    console.log(clicked);
    document.getElementById(modal).classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function buildGalleryModals() {

    videoThumbnails.forEach(function (thumbnail, index) {
        let modalID = 'vid-gallery-modal-' + index, 
            altText = thumbnail.alt;

        thumbnail.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            console.log('thumbnail[i]: ' + index);
        });

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += '<div id="' + modalID + '" class="vid-gallery-modal"><div class="modal-content"><span class="close-button">×</span>' + altText + '</div></div>';
    });
}

buildGalleryModals();
```

```html
<img src="video-embed.jpg" alt="text content1">
<img src="video-embed-copy.jpg" alt="text content2">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: does the `+=` overwrite the entire existing `innerHTML` on `document.body`?

Comment: @Anthony In short, yes. What happens is that it gets a **string representation of the DOM elements** and concatenates your new string to it. This causes any event handlers that might have been set up on those initial elements to be discarded. And, because you are doing this in a loop, it happens over and over again. You wind up with all the HTML, but no handlers because the system sees it as new HTML replacing the old HTML and to the JS runtime, that means new objects replacing the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

The assignments inside the forEach() will not change the original array elements (i.e. videoThumbnails) as they  operate on a copy of the array elements, and not the array elements themselves:

```js
myArray = [1,2,3,4,5]

// try to assign new value to array elements using forEach
myArray.forEach(e => {
            e = '0';
            console.log(e);
        }
    )

// see that elements in original array are unchanged
myArray.forEach(e => {
            console.log(e);
        }
    )
```